# How does fork return a Pid?

Tags: operating-system, fork, pid, systems-programming

I am trying to understand under the hood how does `fork` return the process id of the child since the child method has not returned, nor does it send by other mechanism its id to the parent.  At the lowest level, I do not understand if lets say the child process is a long running loop:

```
//parent code 
    ...some code...
    Pid=fork([see below])
    ...some code...

//some file containing the executable code of the child process
void childProcessRunningMethod()
{
    while(true);
}
```

Who is responsible for assigning the `Pid` to the new process and when does that happen.How does whoever assigns the `Pid` of the child work.

Does the child method gets overwritten into something like:

```
void childProcessRunningMethod(string parentPipeAddress)
{
    var somePipe=new Pipe(parentPipeAddress);
    somePipe.Open();
    somePipe.Send([ Pid]); //somehow generates its own Pid
    somePipe.Close();
    
    while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under the hood `fork` looks something as following:

```
int fork() {
 1. generate a new PID for child                        // executed only by parent process
 2. do million more things required to create a process // executed only by parent
 /* now we have a new process in the system, which can be scheduled on CPU */
 3. finally return value of a specific CPU register     // executed by both parent and child
 // Note that at this point we have two processes, 
 // in case of child process the CPU register contains 0 (fork returns 0 to child)    
 // in case of parent process register contains PID of child
}
```

So as you can see `fork` in parent `process` doesn't have to wait for child in order to return the child's `PID`, as it was already available to parent process.